# MapReduce: How to get mapper to process multiple lines?

Tags: java, hadoop, input, split, mapreduce

#### Goal:

- I want to be able to specify the number of mappers used on an input file
- Equivalently, I want to specify the number of line of a file each mapper will take

#### Simple example:

For an input file of 10 lines (of unequal length; example below), I want there to be 2 mappers -- each mapper will thus process 5 lines.

```
This is
an arbitrary example file
of 10 lines.
Each line does
not have to be
of
the same
length or contain
the same
number of words
```

#### This is what I have:

(I have it so that each mapper produces one "<map,1>" key-value pair ... so that it will then be summed in the reducer)

```
package org.myorg;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.NLineInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;


public class Test {

  // prduce one "<map,1>" pair per mapper
  public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(new Text("map"), one);
    }
  }

  // reduce by taking a sum
  public static class Red extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {      
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf, "pass01");

    job1.setJarByClass(Test.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job1.setCombinerClass(Red.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(Red.class);

    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]));

    // // Attempt#1
    // conf.setInt("mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 5);
    // job1.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);

    // // Attempt#2
    // NLineInputFormat.setNumLinesPerSplit(job1, 5);
    // job1.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);

    // // Attempt#3
    // conf.setInt(NLineInputFormat.LINES_PER_MAP, 5);
    // job1.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);

    // // Attempt#4
    // conf.setInt("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize", 234);
    // conf.setInt("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize", 234);


    System.exit(job1.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

---

The above code, using the above example data, will produce

```
map 10
```

I want the output to be

```
map 2
```

where the first mapper will do something will the first 5 lines, and the second mapper will do something with the second 5 lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [NLineInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.html).

With `NLineInputFormat` functionality, you can specify exactly how many lines should go to a mapper.
E.g. If your file has 500 lines, and you set number of lines per mapper to 10, you have 50 mappers 
(instead of one - assuming the file is smaller than a HDFS block size).

**EDIT**:

Here is an example for using NLineInputFormat:

Mapper Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MapperNLine extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(key, value);
    }

}
```

Driver class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.NLineInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out
                  .printf("Two parameters are required for DriverNLineInputFormat- <input dir> <output dir>\n");
            return -1;
        }

        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        job.setJobName("NLineInputFormat example");
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
        NLineInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 5);

        LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MapperNLine.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Driver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

With the input you provided the output from the above sample Mapper would be written to two files as 2 Mappers get initialized :

part-m-00001

```
0   This is
8   an arbitrary example file
34  of 10 lines.
47  Each line does
62  not have to be
```

part-m-00002

```
77  of
80  the same
89  length or contain
107 the same
116 number of words
```

Comment: How is "NLineInputFormat" properly used? Example? Is this like my "Attempt#2"? (I'm not very strong in java)

Comment: @csiu added an example on how to use `NLineInputFormat` the mapper is very naive just printing out the contents.